# selection with bootstrap tags input not possible

Tags: select, input, tags, bootstrap-5

I am using the bootstrap tags inputs.
here an example:

https://www.cssscript.com/demo/tags-input-bootstrap-5/

I would like to select an tag to copy & paste the value.
in this example you can try to select the tag "Apple".

You can start the selection and when you are finish the selection will lost.

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/XDQvgYm6G5FOaoF5gl

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: so why not open an issue instead of coming here. it seems it's set to focus on input when clicked: https://github.com/lekoala/bootstrap5-tags/blob/master/tags.js#L751

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution: it adds `onclick` listener to each tag, and stops event on click, and also tracks newly added tags, and adds the listener to them, too. Add it after tags initialization code:

```
document.querySelectorAll("select[multiple]:not(#regular) + .form-control > div").forEach(el=>{

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations_list) {

    mutations_list.forEach(function(mutation) {

        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(added_node) {

            added_node.onclick =e=>{e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); return false};
        });
    });
});



observer.observe(el, { subtree: false, childList: true });

})


document.querySelectorAll("select[multiple]:not(#regular) + .form-control > div span").forEach(el=>{

    el.onclick = e=>{e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); return false};

});
```